# Add android platform to Cordova does not work

Tags: android, cordova

I've spent days with Cordova installation with no success. I read numerous forums and watched youtube videos. I tried to install it on Ubuntu and windows. I removed node and Cordova several times. I tried the env settings in several ways. When I try to add Android as a platform to Cordova it says:

Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~7.0.0

and it stacks there doing nothing. Any help would be appreciated as I really don't know what else I could possibly try!?
[cmd output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9rDm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many failed attempts I ended up installing windows 10. Cordova, its Android platform and all related tools installed now. It went seamlessly! I used to have Widows 7 sp1.

If you encounter the same problem during Cordova installation it might help to try a different version of Windows.

My problem solved however, it's still not clear that why I could not install the android on win 7 nor on Ubuntu!?